# Special character from Sqlite GD database android

Tags: android, sqlite, good-dynamics

I am parsing the data from sharepoint server, from there I have some set of documents, that documents I am parsing and storing into Sqlite GD database that data having some special characters. 
I am displaying that data in text view. If I have some special characters I am replacing like that

```
data = data.replace("&quot;", "'");
```

But when I am showing that data in text view after fetching from data base it got converted in some other format like this

[image]

The actual text is “If you’ve got any question or need”. 
I don’t know it’s because GD DB encryption or any other problem in my replacement.
But same thing is working fine with non-GD application. I tried in other application as well.
Please suggest me proper implementation for this.
Thanks in advance.

Good Dynamics
https://community.good.com/community/gdn

Comment: try to use Html.fromHtml(data); instead of replace()